# Sequential translate animations do not work as expected

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to animate 3 translate animations sequentially. I basically want my dialog fragment to move from bottom to top of the screen, and then move a little bit down after reaching to the top of screen and then move to the top again. Here is what I do:

`slide_bottom_in.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>

    <translate
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="10%p"/>

    <translate
        android:startOffset="600"
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="10%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

and in onCreateView() method of my DialogFragment I set:

```
getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.dialogAnimation;
```

and here is the `dialogAnimation` in my styles.xml file

```
<style name="dialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_bottom_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_top_out</item>
</style>
```

But this does not work as I expected. First it moves up **but does not reach to the top of the page**, and then it moves down and up again, but still it does not reach top of the page as expected. After animation ends, the fragment immediately moves to top (without animationg). Any idea about what could be wrong with my xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

First of all, I did not give startOffset to the first translate animation. This is why it did not reach top. Secondly, I need to change fromYDelta and fromXDelta of the third translate animation. The solution below works:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:startOffset="1"
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>

    <translate
        android:startOffset="401"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="7%p"/>

    <translate
        android:startOffset="901"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-7%p"/>

</set>
```